# HttpClient Post request doesn't get back in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, httpclient

I am working on an application where I am sending a POST request using HttpClient but when sending a post request, it keeps loading and doesn't even return any response or any exception. The problem is that when I run the code in a console application it works but when I run the same code in a windows form application which is a vb.net application it doesn't work.

```
   Dim client As New HttpClient()
            Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.paymentgateway-sandbox.com/virtualterminal/v1/orgs/1959874664/transactions/start")
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer token#@$%^&")
            Dim _content As New StringContent("{
  ""transactionData"": {
    ""transactionType"": ""CreditSale"",
    ""method"": ""urlPage"",
    ""submissionType"": ""automatic"",
    ""fields"": [
      {
        ""id"": ""base_amount"",
        ""value"": ""10.00""
      },
      {
        ""id"": ""external_tran_id"",
        ""value"": ""64BFA675-D460-42E6-AFDE-73907B746A2D""
      }
    ]
  }
}", Nothing, "application/json")
            request.Content = _content
            Dim response = Await client.SendAsync(request)
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
            Dim res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
            Console.WriteLine(res)
```

Comment: Show how this code is called, including all the methods involved -- Unrelated: you should generate a JSON by serializing a class object

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's relevant to the solution, but

```
Dim res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

should be

```
Dim res = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

As in the existing form, `res` is a `Task(Of String)`.  It's also a good reminder to never use untyped `Dim` statements.